# how to use fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have an array of links like this:

```
<a title="G0" id="hotel_img_0" rel="hotel_img" href="#"></a>
<a title="G1" id="hotel_img_1" rel="hotel_img" href="#"></a>
<a title="G2" id="hotel_img_2" rel="hotel_img" href="#"></a>
<a title="G3" id="hotel_img_3" rel="hotel_img" href="#"></a>
```

how should I make fancybox work?
I have no class for anchors that is why cannot use `$(".class_name").fancybox()`
I try the same id for all of anchors and `$("#id_value").fancybox()` - fancybox does not work.
Help plese.

Comment: Did you include JQuery? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: there is <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> and no errors in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind fancybox to all elements with the same `rel` attribute (and without having any *class*) like

```
$("a[rel=hotel_img]").fancybox();
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rsV6a/)**

---

**EDIT** :

You could also group elements with different `rel` attributes within the same fancybox initialization script like :

```
$("a[rel=hotel_img], a[rel=standart_room_img], a[rel=agents_room_img]").fancybox();
```

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rsV6a/1/)**

Comment: Thanx a lot. I do not find it at fancybox help/documentation. This helps me: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a[rel*=hotel_img]').fancybox();
    $('a[rel=standart_room_img]').fancybox();
    $('a[rel=agents_room_img]').fancybox();
});
</script>

Comment: @user3720167 : to avoid redundancy, you can group them within the same initialization script. See my edited answer